# UITextField artifact after shifting

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have question about artifacts that appear when `UITextField` is moving in animation block...

Before i move my `UITextField` it looks like this:

[image: UITextField before shifting]

and after moving like this:

[image: UITextField after shifting]

My guess is that it has something to do with fonts after `UITextField` is shifted.

---

here's code that i use for moving `UITextField`:

```
if (answerText.editing)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Moving UITextField" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    movingAnswer = CGPointMake(160,75);
    answerText.center = movingAnswer;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the resulting frame isn't aligned on an even integer. i.e. Moving that amount is causing the frame to be something like (100.5, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0). When you are drawing on a half-pixel boundary, some of the drawing routines are going to make things look blurry to try and make it appear in the correct place. I would print out the frame after the animation and check:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(movingAnswer.frame));
```

If you see any non-integer values, use one of the floor() functions to modify the resulting frame in order to snap it to a boundary.

Comment: You're right!NSLog is returning non-integer value.Thanks for help, i'll try to use one of the floor() funct.